# How can I disable the start menu in Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-ce

how can I disable the start menu! Or completely shut down the entire "explorer" in Windows Windows Mobile 6.1, so that users can not go out of my program.

I have try http://pastebin.com/yz6WN6xa , but then Windows Mobile 6.1 hang.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. Have you perhaps thought that users running your program might not _want_ you to do that? I can see a limited scope where a corporation may want to lock down devices to only run one app (assuming those devices belong to the company) but not much beyond that. Care to enlighten us why you think this is a good idea?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Users who use programs are workers, while their boss should be able to exit the program when he enters a password. Until now I have blocked all hotkyes and buttons that make it possible to go out without entering the password.

Comment: Why the `windows-mobile` tag if you refer to Windows CE?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake there, this is talking about Windows Mobile 6.1. * Updated *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about it myself!

```
Public Class TaskBoard
<DllImport("coredll.dll")> _
Public Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("coredll.dll")> _
Public Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal visible As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function
```

End Class

Then I call the class as follows:

```
TaskBoard.ShowWindow(TaskBoard.FindWindow("HHTaskBar", Nothing), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is setting `ControlBox = false` and having no menu, i.e. `Menu = null` in your Form. It depends on what version your client is running.. This will have more effect on Windows CE 6.5.

[Form.ControlBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText) disables the "X" button and having a `null` [Form.Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.menu(VS.80).aspx) makes your application "full screen", as no buttons will show.

Comment: this I have done:) The problem is that when I focus on another control jumps up the start menu up.

Comment: @sv88erik: What other control do you focus on? Does that control (or dialog) use a menu?

Comment: @ Patrick: It has no menu. When I focus on one text box pops up the start menu.

Comment: By the way, the textbox is inside a user control located inside the dialog. The reason for this is that I have many user controls.

Comment: @sv88erik: Ah yes, of course. Unfortunately I can't help you any further. As paxdiablo commented on, it's a bit intrusive to the users to completely disable the start menu, so it *should* not be easy to accomplish. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The following will temporarily hide the start button while the application is running, please note that if the application crashes you will need to ensure that the HardwareStartKeyEnabled flag is set back to 0.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Shell\BubbleTiles",true).SetValue("HardwareStartKeyEnabled",1);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Shell\BubbleTiles",true).SetValue("HardwareStartKeyEnabled", 0);
    }
}
```